# Scala - standard recursive pattern match on list

Tags: scala

Given:

```
def readLines(x: String): List[String] = Source.fromFile(x).getLines.toList
def toKVMap(fName : String): Map[String,String] =
  readLines(fName).map(x => x.split(',')).map { case Array(x, y) => (x, y) }.toMap
```

I want to be able to take a string and a list of files of replacements and replace bracketed items. So if I have:

`replLines("Hello",["cat"])` and `cat` contains `ello,i!`, I want to get back `Hi!`

I tried:

```
def replLines(inpQ : String, y : List[String]): String = y match { 
  case Nil => inpQ
  case x::xs => replLines(toKVMap(x).fold(inpQ) {
    case ((str: String), ((k: String), (v: String))) =>
      str.replace("[" + k + "]", v).toString
  }, xs)
}
```

I think the syntax is close, but not quite there. What have I done wrong?

Comment: For every condition `<cond>` and conclusion `<conc>`, the statement  'IF `<cond>` AND (`"cat"` contains `"ello,i!"`), THEN <conc>' is logically valid. So,  for example, the statement "if I have:
`replLines("Hello",["cat"])` and `"cat"` contains `"ello,i!"`, every yellow rubber duck can program." is valid. But it is not very helpful, because from false premises, everything follows. Can you somehow convert your code into an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that does not depend on external files? Right now, the question is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is most likely this (note the `foldLeft[String]` instead of `fold`:

```
def replLines(inpQ: String, y: List[String]): String = y match {
    case Nil => inpQ
    case x :: xs => replLines(toKVMap(x).foldLeft[String](inpQ) {
        case ((str: String), ((k: String), (v: String))) =>
            str.replace("[" + k + "]", v)
    }, xs)
}
```

`fold` generalizes the fold initial argument too much, and considers it a `Serializable`, not a `String`. `foldLeft` (and `foldRight`, if you prefer to start your replacements from the end) allows you to explicitly specify the type you fold on

EDIT: In fact, you don't even need a recursive pattern matching at all, as you can map your replacements directly to the list:

```
def replLines2(inpQ: String, y: List[String]): String =
  y.flatMap(toKVMap).foldLeft[String](inpQ) {
    case (str, (k, v)) => str.replace(s"[$k]", v)
  }
```